# How can I make a favorite tag in stack exchange?

Tags: support, ios-app, tag-watching

I want to know can I set some tag as my favorite, so I can easily visit the tag I want in Stack Overflow.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the right panel of a [SE site](https://stackoverflow.com/), you see an entry *"Favorite Tags"*. You can *edit* these tags. You can't *make* your own favorite tags, you can *add* (already created) tags to your list of favorite ones. It requires at least [1'500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to propose the creation of a tag on SO, [500](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) on MSE (and some other sites), but most others only require 300 ([eg](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)).

Questions containing these tags are then in the future **highlighted** (so you can easily visit these questions and answer them). The tags can also be clicked for fast access to questions with that tag.

Similar you can also edit your *Ignored Tags*, questions containing these tags normally don't show up in your list of *Interesting questions*. This is for instance useful if you don't know (much) about that tag. In lists of questions (not the *interesting* feed), they are less opaque (thus *watermarked*) to specify the odds are not that much that you will like/contribute to the content.

Comment: It's works!thank you!so bad I can't just see it,I always go to profile to seek,every time has nothing

Comment: I recently got the "edit without review" privilege; for the moment, I think I'll err on the side of caution when editing others' posts :)

Comment: Do you know - by any chance - whether the required reputation level automatically increases when the number of tags increase? This would be reasonable since it is less likely something isn't defined yet.

Comment: @CommuSoft Not automatically. But the required level is customized on per-site basis by the SE team. [so] requires 1500,  [math.se] 1000, most other sites 300.